# SP 2010: Create list item in a different site which is in a different web app

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, jsom

Is it possible to create list items in a site which is in a different web application using JSOM?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question is asked here - [sharepoint stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109231/using-jsom-or-rest-get-list-items-stored-in-a-different-web-application)

Mostly, cross sites requests aren't possible using conventional JSOM. In case you go for some services, or App architecture, it is achievable. Here are some links that depicts the processes -

[Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24136.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-custom-web-service-wcf-rest.aspx) and 
[MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint/)